# What is the fastest way to perform vector-by-vector dot products for two MxN matrices with small M in CUDA?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, cuda, dot-product

I have two matrices, each of which are `MxN`, where `M = 16` and `N` is much larger (say `n = 262144`, for example).  My goal is to produce a vector of length `N`, where each element corresponds to the dot product of the `nth` vector in each of the matrices.

I have attempted the following approach, where `cIdx` corresponds to the column index of a column vector in each matrix.  Not surprisingly, NVIDIA Visual Profiler is telling me that this approach is mostly memory-bandwidth bound.

```
    public static void MatrixDotProduct(
        float* matrix1,
        float* matrix2,
        float* dotProduct,
        int2 matrixDimensions)
    {
        int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        int stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
        float sum;

        for (int cIdx = i; cIdx < matrixDimensions.y; cIdx += stride)
        {
            int ci = cIdx * matrixDimensions.x;
            sum = 0f;

            for (int j = 0; j < matrixDimensions.x; j++)
            {
                sum += matrix1[ci + j] * matrix2[ci + j];
            }

            dotProduct[cIdx] = sum;
        }
    }
```

I have also found a version of a [vector-by-vector](http://cuda-programming.blogspot.com/2013/01/vector-dot-product-in-cuda-c.html) dot product, which I tried to parallelize as well.  Unfortunately, this ran 20% slower than the above implementation (perhaps it's because my `M = 16`?).  Is there a better way to approach this problem that I'm missing here?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You replaced the inner `for` loop (over `j`) with the linked vector-by-vector dot product? As you say you know the number is very small (is it always `16` or can it be bigger?) it feels right to perform those small dot products in a single thread. Also right now you are performing multiply-add operations which is good. The only problem I see right now is that you do not access the data of `matrix1` and `matrix2` coalesced. (Btw: You do if you introduce the linked vector-by-vector product the way I think you do but it is still slower than your approach.)

Comment: Why don't provide the results of your performance measuring? What bandwidth do you already achieve and what is the theoretical max bandwidth? And note: This is no C++ question at all so you should remove the tag. And right now I am confused: Is this even a cuda kernel? Where is the `__global__` specifier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't an easy case to optimise for because of the lack of data reuse and the small vector sizes (less that a warp). The code should be memory bound, and cache performance will be critical.

One thing to try would be to reduce the volume and increase the efficiency of memory transactions by using a vector type for the loads. I would expect something like:

```
__device__ float vdot(float2 v1, float2 v2) {
    return (v1.x * v2.x) + (v1.y * v2.y);
}

__device__ float vdot(float4 v1, float4 v2) {
    return (v1.x * v2.x) + (v1.y * v2.y) + (v1.z * v2.z) + (v1.w * v2.w);
}

template<typename VT, int NT>
__device__ float vector_dotprod(const VT* v1, const VT* v2) {
    float sum = 0.f;
#pragma unroll
    for (int j = 0; j < NT; j++) {
        sum += vdot(v1[j], v2[j]);
    }
    return sum;
}

template<typename VT, int Nrows>
__global__
void MatrixDotProductPlus(float* matrix1, float* matrix2, float* dotProduct, int2 matrixDimensions)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    int stride2 = stride * Nrows;

    VT* m1 = reinterpret_cast<VT*>(matrix1) + i * Nrows;
    VT* m2 = reinterpret_cast<VT*>(matrix2) + i * Nrows;
    for (; i < matrixDimensions.y; i += stride, m1 += stride2, m2 += stride2) {
        dotProduct[i] = vector_dotprod<VT,Nrows>(m1, m2);
    }
}
```

[Warning: only very lightly tested -- use at own risk]

to be about twice as fast as your code for the `float2` case, and about four times as fast for the `float4` case on Maxwell or Pascal architectures for vectors of length 16. This assumes you know the length of the vectors at compile time and they are round multiples of 2 or 4, although I doubt the loop unroll is as critical as the vector type itself.

Comment: can this benefit from async cuda streams to overlap reads with writes?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: I'm sorry but nothing in your question makes any sense in the context of this question and my answer